# How to use Angular 2 component in Angular 1 app using @angular/upgrade

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade, angular-hybrid

This question might be duplicate but I have tried all possible options.

I am trying to use my Angular 2 component in Angular 1 app using @angular/upgrade.

angular2 files :-

simple hello component in app/components/hello.

hello.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello',
  templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hello.component.scss']
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

hello.component.html

```
<p>
  hello works!
</p>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './components/hello/hello.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HelloComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    HelloComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['usr']);
  }
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

In my Angular 1 app :-
app.ts (root file)

```
import { HelloComponent } from '../angular/src/app/components/hello/hello.component';
import { downgradeComponent } from './node_modules/@angular/upgrade/static/static'

let moduleList = ['ngCookies', 'ngSanitize','$rootScope', '$locationProvider '];
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['usr']);

let app: any = angular.module('usr', moduleList)
.directive(
    'appHello',
    downgradeComponent({ component: HelloComponent })
  );
```

index.html of Angular 1 (I have added base href and root which is default component of angular, app-root component is rendering properly in my angular 1 app)

```
<base href="/">
<app-root></app-root>
```

header.html (angular 1 header component where I want to show my angular 2 hello component)

```
<app-hello></app-hello>
```

screenshots.
[image: Angular 2 root component rendering properly in Angular 1 app]
[image: Angular 2 hello component is not rendering properly in Angular 1 app]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/downgradeModule says

> You cannot use downgradeModule() and UpgradeModule in the same hybrid
>   application. Use one or the other.

This means you can only use downgrade module while bootstrapping NG1

Comment: I am using `downgradeComponent` not `downgradeModule()`.

Comment: you are right (my bad)  . I can see you are both manually bootstrapping and auto-bootstrapping.  
Try removing  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

Comment: I have removed `this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['usr']);` from app.module.ts even then not working but when i added hello component inside root component , it is rendering properly.

Comment: you can't remove this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['usr']); because this is what bootstraps ng1 it's the other one you need to remove